# Why does it show "Queue has been cleared" every time I check 3 questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I recently got the Review Questions privilege, so I know very little stuff about how to review questions.

I was recently reviewing some questions, but after checking 3 questions, it said "This queue has been cleared". I have also experienced this on *[Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tour)*, but I have no clue why this is occurring. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: This question belongs on the mother meta site as you have experienced it across the SE network.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe this message is wrong, i.e. that there *are* more items you could review? "The queue has been cleared" just means the system doesn't have any more items for you to review.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, it shows 3/20 review questions done, and then says this message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The counter "Your daily reviews X/20" just means that you can do a maximum of 20 reviews per day per queue, not that there are actually 20 items in the queue for you to review.

"The queue has been cleared", on the other hand, just means that the queue is empty for you, i.e. there are no more items you are currently eligible to review.